# RAM Upgrade for Mid-2010 MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, memory

So I have a Mid-2010 MacBook and I tried to upgrade the RAM. I put in 2 4GB sticks and it started to beep. I took out one, and it still beeped. When I put in one of the original 1GB sticks and a 4GB stick, it worked. Any help on getting it to 8GB?

Edit: I figured out only one of the 4GB sticks work in the 1/4 configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please take a moment to read the [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and also have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: In addition to what jmh said in his answer... A reason as to why the RAM worked in a 1GB/4GB config and not the 4GB/4GB it may have to do with the brand and type of RAM. On systems that Apple only supports a lessor amount than what _others_ report, it usually requires very specific RAM modules.  Don't just purchase some RAM because it will physically fit and was a good price. Make sure you purchase explicitly that which has been tested and reported to work, even if it costs a bit more then one that physically fits but doesn't work in this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should search for info about your mac on [Everymac.com](https://everymac.com). I searched there for your mac and assuming I did it right I found this brief comment.

> Apple officially supports a maximum of 4 GB of RAM, but third-parties have determined that it actually supports 8 GB of RAM running Mac OS X 10.6 "Snow Leopard" and 16 GB of RAM running OS X 10.7.5 "Lion" or higher and the latest EFI update.

Sounds like it depends on which system you are running. I suggest you go there and see what else you can find or go to [OtherWorldComputing](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/apple/memory/) or [here](https://eshop.macsales.com/memory/maxram)  which reports they sell upgrade kits for your specific Mac.

Comment: I took the RAM from an old HP Pavilion dv6 I had, which had 2 4GB modules by Micron, the same brand that made the 1GB sticks the Mac came with.

Comment: And does this RAM from the old HP operate in your MacBook?

Comment: As said in the question, when I use one of the sticks and an original stick, it works.